# Minimum hard disk required for Sitecore Installation

Tags: site-configuration

Is there any minimum requirement of hard disk for Sitecore installation. I understand the database size will depend on the content but if the database is a separate server, for the CMS and CD part is there any recommended value.

Comment: see http://www.sitecorelessons.com/2016/11/sitecore-hosting-environment.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you'll find any recommendation for HDD size because it totally depends on your needs, configuration and needed modules.

However, a basic Sitecore 9 installation is around 2gb without any css, js, images, custom DLLs or configs. You'll have to estimate these for your project.

You can find xDB requirements [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/platform/hardware_guidlines)

Comment: Thanks Tamer, I got hardware configuration example in the link shared by you.

Comment: But that's for xDB specifically. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes, i understand but that gives a start figure. Hard disk can be further increased based on requirement without much effort.